# How to unsubscribe user from FCM without calling FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM in my Android Application and I am satisfied with it. I'd like to know is there a way to migrate user/group of users from one topic to another without manually calling FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic() on those devices? I'd like to have this possibility on the server-side. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer by myself. Just use   [Google IID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances) for that.